# Rails - error uninitialized constant MyNamespace::OmniauthCallbacksController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, omniauth

I got an error like this:

```
uninitialized constant Mobile::OmniauthCallbacksController
```

It seems like a routes.rb issue.  What exactly do I need to add to my namespace to make it work?

Here is the route scope:

```
  scope :module => :mobile, :as => :mobile do
    constraints(:subdomain => /m/) do
      devise_for :users, :path => "", :path_names =>
               { :sign_in => "login", :sign_out => "logout",
                 :sign_up => "signup" },
                 :controllers => {:sessions => "mobile/sessions" , :passwords => "mobile/passwords" , :confirmations => "mobile/confirmations" , :registrations => "mobile/registrations"}

      get "/home" => "home#index" , :as => "home"

    end
  end
```

Elsewhere in the routes.rb file there is a snippet like this:

```
  devise_scope :user do
    get "auth/:provider" => "users/omniauth_callbacks#passthru"
  end
```

but I am not sure how to make it work within the namespace I am working in.  Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the issue may be in your use of these values for your controllers:

```
 {:sessions => "mobile/sessions" , 
  :passwords => "mobile/passwords" , 
  :confirmations => "mobile/confirmations" , 
  :registrations => "mobile/registrations"
}
```

It looks like the code is getting into these controllers and trying to load `OmniauthCallbacksController` from inside the scope of `Mobile`.

Comment: I see, so what should I do? I still need to have those controllers for the mobile namespace.  Is the problem that I mention the omniauth stuff in there? I used to not have a mention to omniauth in the mobile namespace, but it was still giving that error.